# Showing error while using 'animateWithDuration'

Tags: swift, block, uiviewanimation

I am new in Swift so could not figure out the problem , Please guide me

using It like

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: option, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.btnCallButton.hidden = true
       }, completion: nil)
```

and it showing following error

```
Cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type '(Float, delay: FloatLiteralConvertible, options: UIViewAnimationOptions, animations: () -> Void, completion: NilLiteralConvertible)'
```

please give the required suggestion and also provide some links which describe the blocks in swift

Comment: Note Swift!=Swing.  Please **read** the helpful tag pop-ups before slapping them on a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested closures does not like argument list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022052/nested-closures-does-not-like-argument-list)

Comment: Hidden isn't animatable anyway so you don't need the animation code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) {
  // animate things
  return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hidden is not animatable in Swift. If you want to hide/show via fade in/out use the following code for fadeout

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: options, animations: {
    self.btnCallButton.isHidden = false
    self.btnCallButton.alpha = 0.0
}, completion: { finished in
    self.btnCallButton.isHidden = true
})
```

and following for fadein

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: options, animations: {
    self.btnCallButton.isHidden = false
    self.btnCallButton.alpha = 1.0
}, completion: { finished in

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  `return` at end of closure as

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: option, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.btnCallButton.hidden = true
    return
}, completion: nil)
```