# how to change the speed of falling nodes in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I would like to know how to change the speed of falling nodes in sprite kit using swift, I have tried by changing the gravity, but when it goes very fast it starts to crash.
I have done this, it works, but as I said it crashes:

```
var velocity:CGFloat = 0
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
velocity = CGFloat(score*3)
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -velocity)
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by starts to crash? and why not assign the velocity to the falling body itself?

Comment: @giorashc it starts to shake and disappear and appear. How can i assign the velocity to the falling body itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the scene's gravity, you can apply a force on the nodes.

Disable the gravity

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0)
```

Set the name property of each falling node with it's declaration

```
node.name = @"fallingNode"
```

Then, in the update Function

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("fallingNode", usingBlock: {

    (node: SKNode!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer <ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        // do something with node or stop
        node.physicsBody?.applyForce(velocity)
        return
    })
```

Comment: it gives me this error: Cannot invoke 'applyForce' with an argument list of type '(StringLiteralConvertible, usingBlock: (SKNode!, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)'

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/26022360/2043580 you need to just add return at the end of the closure. Please check the edit.